# Categorise using foreign key in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i want to display the names of product having a particular foreign key at a time

my models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comapny')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

i want it to display company names as list heading followed by list of all products of that particular company but dont know how to filter it like that and display on html

my views.py:

```
class Hydraulic(ListView):
    template_name = 'hydraulics.HTML'
    context_object_name = 'hydraulic'
    model = models.Product
```

can someone tell me how i can filter it for name of foreignkey and inject it in HTML

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In your model, I think you did a typo in the `related_name=comapny` (change to company).*

First, add the queryset to your view and order it by company. Using `select_related` will prevent hitting the database for each company name, since it will already fetched from the initial query.

```py
class Hydraulic(ListView):
    template_name = 'hydraulics.HTML'
    context_object_name = 'hydraulic'
    queryset = models.Product.objects.select_related('company').order_by('company')
```

Then, in your template, you can iterate like this:

```
{% for item in hydraulic %}
 {% ifchanged item.company %}
      <h1> {{ item.company }} </h1>
 {% endifchanged %}
      <div> {{ item }} </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Using the `ifchanged` tag will display the name of company only once, followed by all its products.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer but what to do if there are certain companies and its products which I don't want display on all of the pages

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean but you can exclude some companies in the query using `your_queryset.exclude(company='id_company')` or in the template you can skip with a simple if condition.

Comment: Ok got it thanks and this will work even if products are not sorted according to company name right?

Comment: Yes. The only thing is that the `ifchanged` looks at the previous record so sometimes if two following products in the queryset don't have the same company it might print the company again. But maybe that's also what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hey very sorry to keep on bothering you but I actually don't want company's name to show up twice I just want that 1st company name then all of its products follow by other companies

Comment: Then you need to keep the ordering by company as I mentionned in my answer (with `order_by`). You can't iterate over an unordered queryset and expecting it to be ordered (as in "packed" by company) in your template.